# How do I match Unicode special alpha characters while NOT matching special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I have a dilemma here.  I am trying to write a regex pattern that matches all alpha characters for eastern languages as well as western languages.  One of the criteria is that no numbers can match (so José13) is not a match but (José) is, the other criteria is that special characters cannot match (ie: !@#$% etc.)

I've played around with this in chrome's console, and I've gotten:

```
"a".match('[a-zA-z]');
```

to come back successfully, when I put in:

```
"a".match('[\p{L}]');
```

I get a null response, which I'm not quite understanding why.  According to http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html \p{L} is a  match for any letter.

EDIT: the \p doesn't seem to work in my chrome console, so I'll try a different route.  I have a chart of the unicode from Unifoundry.  I'll match up the regex and attempt to make the range of characters invalid.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by “alpha characters” and “eastern languages”? The approach won’t work, as @icchthedral remarks, so you need to define what exactly you want to include.

Comment: I mean all non-numerical, non-mathematical, non-punctuation characters for all languages.  I don't want someone to be able to enter ResourceReaper, but not ResourceReaper#  OR RésourceRéaper but not RésourceRéaper12 or RésourceRéaper#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in the javascript console, but it seems like a hack:

```
.match('^[^\u0000-\u0040\u005B-\u0060\u007B-\u00BF\u00D7\u00F7]*');
```

However it does what I need it to do.

Referenced this post on SO:  [Javascript + Unicode regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode)

Comment: Unfortunately, with JavaScript's weak Regex and string libraries, this really is the best you can do short of seeing if someone's written more robust libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Current Javascript implementations don't support such shortcuts, but you can specify a range, for example:

```
/[\u4E00-\u9FFF]+/g.test("漢字")
```